# Swap words in string C++

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm a new StackOverflow user! i need help. My task is to find two verbs in the string that are in the list (`_words[]`) and swap them. With string it's not that hard to implement, but I'm only allowed to use `char`.

My idea is this: I split the `char`(`char str[]`) array into words, and assign each word to a constant array(`str2[]`), I do the same with known verbs. Next, I check - if the word in the first array matches the known verb, then I assign the number (`j`) to an integer array in order to know the location of this word. Well, then, with the help of a bubble method, I change their places. But that's bad luck, I looked through the debugger, and for some reason when comparing words, even though the words are the same, the check does not pass. (sorry for my English)

Could you help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I will be grateful!

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)

#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

void words() {
    char str[] = "i like to make programm";
    char _words[] = "like make";
    char* l1 = strtok(_words, " ");
    const char* z[10]; 
    const char* str2[10];
    const char* temp[1];
    int arr_num[2];
    int i = 0, control = 0;
    int word = 0;

    char* stream;

    while (l1 != NULL)
    {
        z[i] = l1;
        l1 = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << z[i] << endl;
    }

    i = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] == ' ') {
            word++;
        }
    }
    word++;
    stream = strtok(str, " ");

    while (stream != NULL)
    {
        str2[i] = stream;
        if(stream == z[0]) cout << "lol";
        stream = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < word; i++) {
        cout << str2[i] << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < word; j++) {
            if ((z[i] == str2[j]) && (control < 3)) {
                control++;
                arr_num[i] = j;
            }
        }
    }

    if (control == 2) {
        temp[0] = str2[arr_num[0]];
        str2[arr_num[0]] = str2[arr_num[1]];
        str2[arr_num[1]] = temp[0];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < word; i++) {
        cout << str2[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: We're not mind readers. We read *code*.  Your code should be [included in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70833153/edit) as a properly formatted [mcve], and include any sample input, expected output, actual output, and debugging efforts and discoveries thus far.

Comment: When you comparing words, do you literally comparing `char*`s? If those pointers point to a different locations, they become different, however the content at the pointed location could be the same.

Comment: soooo sory, i forgot to post the code

Comment: I suppose your task is to swap words within the given string (char array), so that, for example "The **red** _apple is the_ **sweetest** one." becomes "The **sweetest** _apple is the_ **red** one."  That involves not just replacing the two **chosen words** with one another, but also possible shifting the _contents between_ them....

Comment: @zerocukor287 , yes, I do it the way you said. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: @CiaPan , yes, I know, but I need at least a minimum)

Comment: @arnold yes, I can, and i would advise you do it since what you're doing now will not necessarily reap the points of the question. I'll post it as best an answer as I can *without* giving the actual code away, if desired.

Comment: @WhozCraig , i will be very glad for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posted only because the OP asked for an alternative algorithm of how this can be done. There are other ways, but this has the benefit of being done entirely in place, using no additional storage besides some pointers and some lengths.

This task can be done in-place, by using a utility function to reverse a character sequence, given a pointer and length (or two pointers). You must have numerous other *reliable* operations at your disposal as well, including the ability to find *complete* words. (e.g. words that are preceded by whitespace or begin-of-string, and succeeded by whitespace or end-of-string. Write those, and test them *thoroughly*. Once you've done that, consider the following.

**String**

```
this is a very simple sample of words
```

**Test Words**

```
very of
```

We start by separating our two words, which you're already doing. Next we find both words, remembering their locations, using your well-tested utility functions. We know their lengths, so we can therefore calculate where they begin, and where they end.

```
this is a very simple sample of words
          1111               22
```

Side note: When doing this, you'll discover the *order* may be backward. For example, if your word list was `of very`, then the result would have your word positions looking like this:

```
this is a very simple sample of words
          2222               11
```

It doesn't matter, all that matters is that once you find both words, the word closest to the beginning of the string is the "first" word, and the one coming later is the "second" word from here on out.

That said (and now back to our original labeling), reverse the entire segment from the beginning of the first word through the end of the second word, *not* including any whitespace preceding the first, or succeeding the second:

```
this is a fo elpmas elpmis yrev words
          22               1111
```

Next, reverse the two words in-place at their new homes.

```
this is a of elpmas elpmis very words
          22               1111
```

And finally, reverse all characters *past* the end of the new first word until (but not including) the beginning of the new second word, *including whitespace*  That means this region:

```
this is a of elpmas elpmis very words
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

and it becomes this:

```
this is a of simple sample very words
```

That's the entire algorithm. Once you find your word locations and extents you're literally four well-place segment reversals from accomplishing your goal. Obviously, care must be undertaken to ensure you do not precede before beginning of string, nor exceed past the end-of-string, should your words being swapped reside in those locations.

---

**Update** : OP-provided sample.

The OP provided a sample, apparently not understanding how the above algorithm applies, so I'm running it through that sample as well

Words

```
like eat
```

Sentance

```
I like to eat apples
```

Step 1: Locate the two words, noting their position and lengths.

```
I like to eat apples
  1111    222
```

Step 2: Reverse the full segment from the beginning of the first word through the end of the second. Therefore, the segment marked with 'x' below:

```
I like to eat apples
  xxxxxxxxxxx
```

becomes this:

```
I tae ot ekil apples
  222    1111
```

Step 3: Reverse each word now that they're in their new locations

```
I eat ot like apples
  222    1111
```

Step 4: Reverse the full segment *between* the two words, including whitespace. E.g. the segment marked below:

```
I eat ot like apples
     xxxx
```

becomes this:

```
I eat to like apples
```

And you're done.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I meant for example:
i like to eat apples -> i eat to like apples

Comment: @arnold I think you misunderstood WhozCraig – the answer is precisely what you said in your comment.

Comment: ok i will try to understand this answer!

Comment: @arnold Please see another example of swapping the second and the fourth word in `Ab Cde Fghij Klmnopq Rst`. Find both words in the string first. Then reverse in-place both words, as well as the part between them (which _may_ be empty): `Ab edC jihgF qponmlK Rst`. Finally reverse them all as one substring: `Ab Klmnopq Fghij Cde Rst`. Done.

Comment: Thanks, but I accomplished this using ```string```)